# Grails application Complaint with the REST

Tags: grails

I have made an grailsapplication. Now i have to make it complaint with the REST protocol. how do i do this ? can i get any material where i have examples of how to carry out this process ??groovygrails

Answer (score 1):

See section 13.1 of the manual at the following link.
http://www.grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/13.%20Web%20Services.html

Answer (score 0):

there is a great grails plugin called jaxrs www.grails.org/plugin/jaxrs.
to install it on your grails app just run

grails install-plugin jaxrs

get more info here http://code.google.com/p/grails-jaxrs/